# Linux: How to find out which other program writes to serial

Tags: linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am working on a Raspberry PI running Raspbian, which is connected to a microcontroller via serial communication (using a PHP script).
This is working only partly... After the first message the microcontroller answers with an acknowledge (which is ok) - but the computer answers to this acknowledge with some rubbish sequences (^F (pause) \ \ \ ), while my program is paused (usleep()).

I am not an linux expert, so I need some help with this...
My question: How do I find out which other programs are writing to the serial?

Note: I already disabled the serial login.

Comment: additional information:
I am not able to read the incoming messages - I monitor the traffic with an oscilloscope (which is able to decode rs232)

Comment: If I do the same using a shell script instead of my program, the problem disappears...

Comment: Are you using canonical mode?  Post your initialization code.  BTW 0x06 or ^F in ASCII code is an Acknowledgement.

Comment: I use PHP-Serial ([link](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial)) to ease my work - i think it uses non-canonical mode.
The ^F are two(!) characters/bytes, but the hint that this could mean acknowledge is interesting... 

Also, I tested the same thing with a python script, which works...
The weird fact: after one time of running this script, also my php script works - and when I reboot I have to run the python script again